# Annoying delay when killing a buffer containing an executing process

Tags: emacs, process, elisp, hook, defadvice

Every time I kill a buffer containing an executing process in Emacs I get an annoying ~2 second delay before my interaction continues. And when that happens I get the message

```
error in process sentinel: Selecting deleted buffer
```

The tricky problem is that it only happens in my Emacs configuration and not in Vanilla Emacs. I'm guessing the delay happens because of an extra hook or advice activated in one or some of my modules loaded.

Does anybody recognize the error message and know which hook or advice that might be causing this problem? I've tried searching the web without any luck.

Comment: "Does anybody have a clue to where to start digging?" Pretty hard to say since you haven't provided your config. Comment half of it out, see if the bug is fixed, repeat.

Comment: I rephrased my question.

Comment: I'am aware of the binary search. It's just that...that will take hours. I try asking here first. If somebody already have had this problem and quickly can report the solution I don't see why asking this question should be bad.

Comment: Although rewarding, Emacs is unfortunately a substantial investment of time to get things configured to a user's particular tastes -- bug-fixes can take a zillion hours or just a few minutes to implement.  It may behoove you to split up your user configuration into several different files so that you can simply comment out the `require` statement(s) in your master `init.el` -- then the binary search is reduced to that one particular library which is the likely suspect (i.e., when it works properly after commenting out the `require` statement).

Comment: Hi Per. If you're lucky and someone recognizes the problem described and has a solution, great. If not, a binary search of whatever is included in your Emacs config is the right approach. **The more code in your config, the more potent a binary search is.** It doesn't sound quick, but it is. Narrow it down to a file that you load (maybe your init file, maybe a file it loads). Then narrow it down within that file. It's dumb and blind, but it's smart to use a binary search, even if it doesn't take a lot of reasoning to use it. Update the question with what you find, if the solution is not clear.

Comment: There are multiple possible causes of this error. It isn't as if there is just one possible package or config which could cause it. Without providing your config, we are only guessing. You could try looking at what modes you have loaded in that buffer before killing it. That might narrow down the search.